# Parse namespace to values file

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, haproxy-ingress

I'm trying to add the `{{ .Release.Namespace }}` to a string, but it's parsed literally as just `{{ .Release.Namespace }}` and not as the namespace itself. I've tried using quotes (`"`) and using `tpl`, but nothing did the job. I'm using Helm v3.5.4.

In context:

```yaml
config:
  config-proxy: |-
    _front__tls
      # BEGIN::Redirect to openBalena VPN
      acl is_ssl req.ssl_ver 2:3.4
      use_backend {{ .Release.Namespace }}_openbalena-vpn_443 if !is_ssl
      # END::Redirect to openBalena VPN
```

Whole `values.yaml` is found [here](https://github.com/bartversluijs/open-balena/blob/k8s-support-v3.2.1/k8s/chart/values.yaml), and the above snippet is located [here](https://github.com/bartversluijs/open-balena/blob/k8s-support-v3.2.1/k8s/chart/values.yaml#L162-L168).
I'm using the [HAProxy Ingress Helm Chart](https://github.com/haproxy-ingress/charts/tree/master/haproxy-ingress).

In some parts, as you can see in the `values.yaml`, are also using `{{ .Release.Namespace }}`, but those are parsed fine (like the TCP options for example).

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `values.yaml` files (and its `--set` friend) are not subject to interpolation, as I'm sure that would be a security risk. If you want `.Values.config.config-proxy` to be interpolated, you can use helm's [`tpl` function](https://helm.sh/docs/howto/charts_tips_and_tricks/#using-the-tpl-function)

Comment: Thanks! Only thing is, when using the `tpl` function, it has to be done in the template yaml files and not in the `values.yaml` right? So only option is to change the behaviour in the Chart templates how it's parsed?

Comment: @mdaniel would mind converting your comment into the answer since it addresses the OP question?

Comment: @BartVersluijs yes, that's correct; the `values.yaml` does not execute any dynamic content (that's the original problem you were facing). If you are merely trying to replace the namespace, then using `tpl` may be more trouble than it's worth. If you have a lot of those gotmpl expressions, then patching the chart is the only way

Answer (score 1):

It should work if you have `config-proxy` place in `<chart_root_dir>/files/config-proxy` and use tpl function to load it in your template like this:

```
config:
{{ tpl (.Files.Glob "files/config-proxy").AsConfig .  | indent 2 }}
```

Not sure about how nested your config key is i your template, so you might adjust the indent level from the example.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! However, can I use that in the `values.yaml`, or do I have to do that in the Chart templates? Because I'm trying to set a config of a dependency chart.

When I try this in the `values.yaml`, I get the following error:

`Error: cannot load values.yaml: error converting YAML to JSON: yaml: invalid map key: map[interface {}]interface {}{"tpl (.Files.Glob (\"files/haproxy.config.yaml\")).AsConfig . | nindent 6":interface {}(nil)}`

Comment: I didn't know it was an excerpt of your values.yml. You cannot use templating in the there, sorry. I myself have used this in config-maps, but it yhould work in all yamls in the templates folder

Comment: Ah okay, thanks! I'll try another solution for my problem then. Weird thing is that the `{{ .Release.Namespace }}` in another config in my `values.yaml` is being parsed, so I don't know why this isn't parsed...

Answer (score 0):

After investigating it some more and with the help of @Minato and @mdaniel (thanks for that), I came to the conclusion that it simply isn't possible using the `values.yaml` alone. I've created a PR in the Chart.

Before the PR, the values were parsed like this:

```
{{- toYaml .Values.controller.config | nindent 2 }}
```

I've changed that to:

```
{{- tpl (toYaml .Values.controller.config) . | nindent 2 }}
```

And now it parses the `{{ .Release.Namespace }}` fine!